# Keep Ajax Session Alive When Reloading Page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to keep a login session when I **reload the page**, but it doesn't work.

Here is my login post:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mauriciogiordano.com/allmej/public/user/auth',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {username: 'user', password: 'user'},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

To check if the user session is open:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mauriciogiordano.com/allmej/public',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

OBS: to check if the session is open, expand the Auth object. User must be true.

Thanks!

Comment: ajax runs in the browser, sessions are a key with in the browser and the server, the best way for this, in my opinions are `cookies`

Comment: Unless you do something to kill the session, it should stay alive by itself.

Comment: @Barmar he is doing a login true ajax, so the browser doesnt know about he session with the server. are you sure about that mate?

Comment: It stay alive until I reload the page...

Comment: If it's a PHP-style session, all the browser has to do is keep sending back the PHPSESSID cookie. AJAX will do that automatically.

Comment: How are you implementing the login session on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive a response from your login AJAX request, you need to either through a Session ID in the URL (query string) or by dropping a cookie with the session id, provide some way for the server to recognize the client on subsequent requests.

Comment: adding the sessionid to the URL (URL rewriting) is considered bad practice - in terms of security.

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript XHR, or as others call it, AJAX.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Using ajax you can call a php script that refreshes your session every 10 minutes